# Rails Model Association with form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am trying to achieve this:

1. It has a model called Customer that has details of the customers name
   (first, middle and last) and telephone numbers (mobile and landline).
2. It has a model called Address that is linked to Customer. This model
   will have details for a customers address (a number of address lines,
   a country and a post/zip code).
3. A customers controller that supports two pages. The first will list
   all customers in the database along with their associated address.
   The second will display a form for the entry of a new customer along
   with their address and allow for the creation of a new customer and
   address record. It should be possible to move from either page to the
   other without having to enter an URL in the browser navigation bar.
   A number of points of note about this are as follows...

This is my code:

Migration:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :addresses do |t|
   t.string :address_line1
   t.string :address_line2
   t.string :address_line3
   t.string :city
   t.string :county_province
   t.string :zip_or_postcode
   t.string :country
   t.string :customer_id

   t.timestamps null: false
 end

 create_table :customers do |t|
  t.string :first_name
  t.string :middle_name
  t.string :last_name
  t.integer :mobile_number
  t.integer :landline_number

  t.timestamps null: false
 end
end
end
```

Model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for([@address,@customer]) do |f| %>
<% if @customer.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this customer from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :first_name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :middle_name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :middle_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :mobile_number %><br>
  <%= f.number_field :mobile_number %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :landline_number %><br>
  <%= f.number_field :landline_number %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address_line1 %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :address_line1 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address_line2 %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :address_line2 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address_line3 %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :address_line3 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :city %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :city %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :county_province %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :county_province %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :zip_or_postcode %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :zip_or_postcode %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :country %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :country %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :addresses do
  resources :customers  
end
resources :customers do
  resources :addresses  
end
```

I haven't changed anything in my both controllers.

I am getting this error: undefined method `address_line1' for #

I don't understand where i am wrong. Any help? :( please

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150722160725) do

  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "customer_id"
  t.string   "address_line1"
  t.string   "address_line2"
  t.string   "address_line3"
  t.string   "city"
  t.string   "county_province"
  t.string   "zip_or_postcode"
  t.string   "country"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end

add_index "addresses", ["customer_id"], name:   "index_addresses_on_customer_id"

create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "middle_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.integer  "mobile_number"
  t.integer  "landline_number"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end

end
```

Comment: i think  `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is what your are looking for  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: @bhanu i tried friend still no luck :(

Comment: Can you copy/paste your schema here? I have a hunch you just added those fields manually after the initial migration.

Comment: Have you updated all your forms, models and controllers?

Comment: @ItoA please have a look i copy paste my schema up there.

Comment: I tried has_one but still not working...